# database relationships one table join with other table based on the user choice?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, database-design

This picture of my tables in the database :

[image]

In what fields do I need to make a connection table ?

and user form :

For example, a user form, this figure is almost .

When the user add table name to treeview , questions relating to the same table will appear .

Now may communicate simultaneously with 3 to Table .

Finally, we report user's choices and responses .

[image]

And report like this picture :

[image]

Thank you my friends

Please tips me for continue working .

Comment: It is rather unclear as to what your question actually is.  Please rephrase it or use a better example.

Comment: It looks like your data model won't support this. You have to have a way of linking the enquiry to the other tables and its missing. However, the way you would link them depends on questions like: how many enquiries will be linking to them? will one row in e.f. Air always be linked to the same Enquiry? Or can one Air be linked to multiple Enquiries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an intermediate table to provide the links:

```
InquiryID
NodeType  (value related to an enum listing Compact, Air, Traditional)
NodeID  (this is either CompactID, AirID, or TraditionalID)
//other fields?
```

This table could provide either 1:1 or 1:many links (duplicate InquiryID related to more than one NodeID).

So records might look like:

```
1  |  1
1  |  2
2  |  1
3  |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry,  is some situations that is normal that you can't create FOREIGN KEY constraint. You just should start distinct situations where DBMS should mange data consistency from the situations where this yours responsibility.

And the case of inquiry / orders - is exactly such situation.